# Moving in the Hurwitz Space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces

To my very limited understanding, a Hurwitz space parameterizes branched coverings $(\Sigma,f)$ with a set of given branching data. Here $f:\Sigma\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ is a nonconstant holomorphic map from a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ to the complex projective line.

Now assume that we begin with a fixed $f:\Sigma\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ such that $f^*\mathcal{O}(2)=K_\Sigma$, where $K_\Sigma$ is the canonical bundle of $\Sigma$. This map corresponds to a point $p$ in the corresponding Hurwitz space. If we move the point $p$ in its (connected component of) Hurwitz space continuously, can the condition $f^*\mathcal{O}(2)=K_\Sigma$ be preserved?
For the case $\Sigma$ is of genus 3 and $f$ is a branched double cover, the answer is affirmative. I would like to know if this is true in general. Any suggestion of proof or reference is welcome!

Thank you!